Passport application for a minor with divorced parents
I share custody of my child with my ex-husband, and she currently lives with him in another state. We are planning an international trip next year and I’m working on our passport applications. If I'm applying for her passport, can I list my address on her application to ensure it gets mailed to me?

We live in the US, will be traveling to Iceland in 2025. Our child is under 16 & her dad wouldn’t stop us from being able to travel with her, but I know he won’t pay for the passport & I wouldn’t be surprised if he held onto the passport and not give it to me.

Will the father cooperate in applying for a child passport that will be mailed to you? Is your child over 16? For some background on this issue, review the answers posted to this Travel.SE question.

To clarify, will it be a US passport that you will be applying for for your child?

The page on US passports for children under 16 is here. Normally, the child and both parents (if both have custody) need to appear in person. If one or both parents cannot attend, then the parent(s) who cannot attend can have a DS-3053 notarized, to be presented with the child when applying. I don't think it's possible for the child to not appear in person at the time of application.
So I think what would normally happen when parents live apart is that the parent who doesn't live with the child would do DS-3053, and the parent who lives with the child would apply for the passport in person together with the child. But in this case, you don't want the parent who the child lives with to apply for the passport (because you don't want the passport to go to him, and because he doesn't want to pay for it).
So I think some possible options are:

You go to where the child lives, and apply in person with the child and the father, and you can pay and put your address on the application. Or
If the child visits you sometimes, you can have the father have a DS-3053 notarized, and you will apply in person with your child when your child visits you.

